# Zip File Doesn't Appear in Apache Directory (Centos)

Tags: apache-http-server, centos

I'm testing Centos 6.3 on my laptop.  It's kind of a confounded thing that when I place example.zip in /var/www/html/folder, I can't see it at http://www.mysite.com/folder. The command that I run to zip the file (mp3 folder) is:

zip -r example.zip example

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?  I do not experience this type of issue on my Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you can't see it?  What happens when you access the folder?

Comment: Oddly, when I reinstalled the OS this morning, the behavior described in my post seems to have resolved itself.